# c++ segmentation fault on valid pointer

Tags: c++

I am getting a segmentation fault on a call on a member function of a pointer. However, it looks like the pointer is valid as the call to another member just before works fine and the debugger shows that the pointer seems to point somewhere. It also shows all the members of the pointer with valid values

```
    m_callListener @0x1fe2b68 CallListener
    m_requests             10         long
    m_waiting_r             3         long




void Handler::onCall()
{
    if (m_state == Waiting)
    {

        m_callListener->logWaiting();

    }
    m_callListener->onCall(); // <--SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
}

void CallListener::logWaiting() { m_waiting_r += 1; }
```

I only know segmentation fault errors form de-referencing null pointers, accessing an array out of its bounds or trying to write access const values and googling brings up mostly answers related to those. But it if I am not mistaken, I have a valid pointer and there is no array involved and no constant values. What could be the reason for the segfault here? any hints how I can approach debugging this? I am fairly clueless where to even start and what to post here to make things clearer

Comment: Please post complete code. Might be issue is somewhere else..

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant. It is a massive library, so I don't even know what to post... also I am not supposed to post any original code, unfortunately, so I can only replicate, hopefully without losing the important parts.
I would be already happy if people could tell me how to try to debug this

Comment: If `m_callListener` is of type `Handle *` the statement `m_callListener->onCall()` is infinitely recursive.   A similar problem can arise if `onCall` is virtual, and the derived class versions call `Handler::onCall()`.

Comment: For segmentation to occur with out of bound array access, it may occur due to writing or reading from illegal location. Your pointer may have been modified, it may be pointing somewhere else in the memory region, in such case SIG_SEGV is thrown by the System.

Comment: @Peter it is a different class CallListener

Comment: Completely different class, or a derived class?

Comment: @ Nishanth if my pointer would have been modified, how can it still show the right member values in the debugger?

Comment: @Peter completely different

Comment: In that case, you're going to need to provide an MCVE.   You haven't given enough information for people to help.

Comment: ok, let me try to come up with more information